# Will_paginate gem conflicts with Bootstrap built in panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap two tabs panel on my ruby-on-rails app view where each tab shows different contents, and I generate a pagination for each tabs. It works perfectly for the first tab. However, when I am on the second tab, clicking next page sends me back to the first panel. I understand that the problem is that when I click next page button, the page gets refreshed. I haven't add any JS yet. Any suggests on how to solve this conflict? Thank you!

This is request view:

```
   <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default" id = "requests">
      <div class="panel-head">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
          <li class="active"><a href="#pendingrequests" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="filestab" role="tab" data-link = "/homestays/<%= params[:id] %>/pending_requests" data-activetab="pending">Pending Requests</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pastrequests" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="filestab" role="tab" data-link = "/homestays/<%= params[:id] %>/past_requests" data-activetab="past">Past Requests</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="pendingrequests">
            <%= render 'requests/pending_requests', :locals => {:pending_requests => @pending_requests} %>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pastrequests">
            <%= render 'requests/past_requests', :locals => {:past_requests => @past_requests} %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the partials:
_pending_requests:

```
<% pending_requests.each do |request| %>
  <div class = "col-md-6" id = "request_panel">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="user-picture">
        <%= image_tag("find_user_rsz.png") %>
      </div>
      <div class = "name"> <%= request.name %> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @pending_requests, param_name: 'pending' %>
```

_past_request:

```
<% past_requests.each do |request| %>
  <div class = "col-md-6" id = "request_panel">
    <div class="text-center">
      <div class="user-picture">
        <%= image_tag("find_user_rsz.png") %>
      </div>
      <div class = "name"> <%= request.name %> </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @past_requests, param_name: 'past' %>
```

And this is my controller action:

```
def requests
end

def pending_requests
   @pending_requests = current_user.responses.paginate(:page => params[:pending], :per_page => 1)
end

def past_requests
   @past_requests = Student.all.paginate(:page => params[:past], :per_page => 1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta change the params for will_paginate. At the moment you have page for both I guess.

```
  def get_files #loading files data with js on common_medias page
    @common_files = @conversation.messages.with_file.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:files], per_page: 14)
    respond_to :js
  end

  def get_links #loading links data with js on common_medias page
    @message_links_pre = @conversation.messages.with_link.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:links], per_page: 14)
    @message_links = @message_links_pre.map { |f| { link: f.link, created_at: f.created_at, user_id: f.user_id} }.flatten
    @common_links = formatting_links(@message_links)
    respond_to :js
  end
```

and the html in the partials

```
<%= will_paginate @common_files, param_name: 'files'

<%= will_paginate @message_links_pre, param_name: 'links'
```

common html (basic html where all the content will be loaded by js; partials are added to the different tabpanels)

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#filestab" aria-controls="filestab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-link = "<%= get_files_user_common_medias_path(@user)%>" data-activetab="file">Files</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#linkstab" aria-controls="linkstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-link = "<%= get_links_user_common_medias_path(@user)%>" data-activetab="link">Links</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#calendarstab" aria-controls="calendarstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-activetab="calendar">Calendar</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="filestab">
        <%= render @common_files %> #for html version only
        <%= will_paginate @common_files, param_name: 'files'
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="linkstab">
        <%= render @common_links %> #for html version only
        <%= will_paginate @message_links_pre, param_name: 'links'  
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="calendarstab">
         #I haven't implemented calendar yet, so tab is empty at the moment
      </div>
    </div>
```

js (not necessary, if you render partials on page load)

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
  var target = $(this).data("activetab");
  var href = $(this).data("link");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: href,
    data: {tab: target},
    dataType: "script"
  });
});
```

UPDATE:

So let's stick with the html version for now, which means all the data will be loaded. It's a good solution, if you have 3 tabs 10 records/page then you have to load 30 records. Where this solution gets screwed up is the page changing. 3 tabs and then html pagination. You could use html initial load and then every page could have infinite scrolling. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQX2fgB6y10).

Now the partials:

1st approach:

requests.html.erb (or the page u are at)

```
`<%= render 'folder/pending_requests'` and then the partial:
```

_pending_requests:

```
 <% @pending_requests.each do |pending_request| %>
   <%= pending_request.name %>
   .........
 <% end %>
 <%= will_paginate @pending_requests %> #this line can be in the partial or just under the render 'folder/.....; her it doesn't matter
```

2nd approach:

requests.html.erb (or the page u are at)

```
 <%= render @pending_requests %>
 <%= will_paginate @pending_requests %> #must be here, can't be in the partial since the partial is just for 1 record
```

_pending_request.html.erb #name must be singular version of the rendered version, this refers to just one record

```
 <%= pending_request.name %> #rails convention you don't need @
 ......
```

Which one is better? If you can go with the second one, since you will have the reusable partials, which will come in handy when you wanna work with js. (read about it, it's worth it)

UPDATE 2:

html approach controller (You want all your data loaded on 1 request, so all the data you need has to be loaded.)

```
def requests
  @past_requests = .....
  @pending_requests = ......
end
```

js approach

```
def request
  #any other data you need on initial page load like
  @users = .....
  @profiles = ........
end

#when you make the js action request you have to loaf the data from these actions/routes, so reuqest will go to for instance /pending_requests and fetches the @pending_reuqests. 
def pending_requests
   @pending_requests = ......
   respond :js #read comment below
end

def past_requests
   @past_requests = ...... #read comment below
end
```

## comment for js response

It's a js response so page won't be reloaded, so you stay on /requests page. What you do with the js respoonse it's up to you. In rails you can assemble it on server side with js.erb and then append it to the existing dom `$('#thistab').append(<%= j render @pending_requests %>`) --> This means you can load the whole partial, which was already created on rails side, so browser will kknow how to load it. Rails conventions prefers this since you can reuse the partials and you don't have to assemble the html on client side. If you send back via json, then you have to tell exactly on js files what to do with the data ,like `$('#thistab').append(<li>data.name</li><li>data.created_at</li>)` which makes you write a bunch of code. Basically you have to rewrite to whole partial here. Json is good approach if you need to manipulate the data on client side or you don't need to load a bunch of html like in this case.

Comment: Thank you! I just added my original controller action to my question. This is how I changed my controller action:
    `def requests 
        @pending_requests = User1.all.paginate(:page => params[:pending], :per_page => 1) 
        @past_requests = User2.all.paginate(:page => params[:past], :per_page => 1) 
    end`
Do I understand your answer correctly? If so, it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you added the param_name in the view?

Comment: Szilard Magyar, I did. It didn't work. I just separated them into two pages. In order to fix the problem, I assume I had to override something in the gem. I just thought it is not worth to spend too much time on that. Unless you have other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: It's weird. It is working fine for me. Maybe because you are using 2 paginations within the same action. You don't have to separate into 2 pages. Just create 2 different actions. Updated my answer. As u see the data-link attribute tells which action gets activated.

Comment: In this way, the info for each tab only gets loaded when it is activated? Do I need to add ajax code for that since I assume I can't hit two actions at the same within one page.

Comment: You don't have to use the js version. It's up to you. I have it cuz page load is faster this way. Updated the answer again.

Comment: I edited my post. That's what I did based on your recommendation. Do I get it right? Now it throws an error that @pending_requests is undefined. How does it know to hit both actions when the page is loaded for the first time? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You are mixing the 2 approaches (I thought you knew how to do, so my answer wasn't precise). Either you call the partial based on location (<%= render 'folder/pending_requests') and then put the each loop and the will paginate in that one partial OR you are using the following rails convention https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-partial_refactoring

Comment: see previous comment, check out the link, then check out my updated answer

Comment: I am sorry. I think I did the first approach. I did call the partials in requests.html.erb the way you say. However, those variables are from other two actions: pending and past requests. By just calling request action won't give \@pending_requests and \@past_requests to the partials. That's why my question is that how to get those variables in the first place without hitting the other two actions. Isn't my updated code the same as your first approach? Did I miss something?

Comment: When you make a request it goes to a given action. If you do the html approach it means 1 request points to 1 action (def requests action with the same route name /requests) then you should have only one action, with all the instance varaibles under each other. Code updated again.

Comment: Szilard Magyar. I really appreciate your help. However, the deadline is getting closer, so I have to move on to implement another feature. Maybe later I will come back to try this out.